# Way of typing an object to be two+ variations without using a discriminated union special field in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, union

I run into this situation a lot, and have just run into it, getting this error:

```
Property 'id' does not exist on type 'Filter'.
  Property 'id' does not exist on type '{ slug: string; language: { slug: string; }; }'
```

For this code ([TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEDMEsBsBcFMBOpHwMYHtEBNQCMBPUSbAGlC3yIGdoBXAc1AGpRoBDAOwbvYfgBQsAgAd4oAGIwEyALygA3sWwAuUNViJI3UAF9QAH0Xr6DNRq3cA3Gy48+8NUtqNzm7U326BA8HU5osJAYnKAAjnRIBAAUUHBIalLxiACUigKgmcTgoLHSSAB0JGkKGVnlmJzUGNDwBdAYDNEA5BFRVMrNKWWZ+vDQ1OKl5RUh1bX1jS1tiESEJowstty8-AUuDF09egLeQqLiSTIAgrAIALYisABMoPJKwmJqzeAAjM3kJG6WnobGj45QC9rh8FmZ1O5rMt7PwnGDvh49DtfP5AsFQjMCNc8slEvlEKcLldriVtpAcjiZAUAXdZPIXu9SSMspVxnUGk1WpFZh0SKC4lTits+gMhttRlUauyplz2vMNksOCsHOtTPz8arGOQBYUlTC6htuuVvLogA)):

```
// filter record by id, or by slug + language
type Filter = { id: string } | { slug: string; language: { slug: string } }

function query(filter: Filter) {
    if (filter.id) {
        console.log('query by id')
    } else {
        console.log('query by slug + language.slug')
    }
}
```

How can I allow this case to pass somehow?

Basically, I want to have it so you can define "scenarios" or "alternatives" of query parameters you can use for filtering. There could be 5+ variants for a given filter/query. How can I solve this, perhaps in some clever way?

I don't want to resort to using a special field for discriminated unions I don't think, like adding a "type" field, or something like that:

```
type FilterAttempt2 = { type: 'f1', id: string } | { type: 'f2', slug: string; language: { slug: string } }

function query2(filter: FilterAttempt2) {
    if (filter.type === 'f1') {
        console.log('query by id', filter.id)
    } else {
        console.log('query by slug + language.slug', filter.slug, filter.language.slug)
    }
}
```

As you can see from the playground, that works. But that is not very maintainable / readable, having to come up with a name for each filter combination. Any other solutions?

You could make it more readable:

```
type FilterAttempt3 = { type: 'by_id', id: string } | { type: 'by_slug_and_lang_slug', slug: string; language: { slug: string } }
```

But that comes with all kinds of undesirables, like the names being arbitrary and long and mostly meaningless other than for the TS compiler, doesn't work well for more complex filters, etc.. You would be better calling them `filter1` and `filter2`, but that is no good either.

Wondering if there are any other ways to accomplish this goal in a nice way.

The only other option I can think of is to have 1 method per filter type, but that I am not a fan of for similar reasons as well.

If the wedge I'm trying to put this in isn't good practice, please explain why it's not, and what is better instead.

Comment: `if ("id" in filter)`

Comment: [`in` operator narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-in-operator-narrowing) is the conventional way to do this (despite being technically unsound and despite it being similar to the thing everyone wants to do which is just a truthiness check on the property)